# Changing "0.0.0" string to a value (Double)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently creating a dashboard for my internship and I have stumbled upon a problem.

A dashboard item checks how many users have their iPads up-to date with the version. 
The data base gives numbers in for example iOS version: 4.3.0 , 4.4.2 etc.

Then, I ask Excel to put a "Yes" for all version from 11.0.1 and higher (Greater) and everything less than 11.0.1 to put a "No" 
--> Formula: =IF([@Version]>=$j$2, "Yes", "No")

[image: Picture:]

The picture shows the Table with the headers:
Version --> iOS version
Value --> I have tried to translate the versions into value with =VALUE(I5) etc for every version
Complaince --> Should say Yes if version is up-to-date, no if not.

OK from is the input for the version ($J$2 in IF formula)

In red I have marked what is incorrect, and green what is correct.

So my question, how can I get this system to work, the formula reads the versions as strings, maybe there is a way to get numbers (double/integer) out of them.

Comment: Hi, in my oppinion you could use `Left/Right/Mid/Len'. The idea is to check len of version they've got if it it's "5" then check only left version because it will be for ex. 4.0.6 vs 11.0.2 then 4<11 "No". If len is 6 then you should check left then mid and right part of it to see if numbers are the same or one is lower/higher than set value 11.0.1 after that return "Yes", "No".

https://www.excel-exercise.com/left-right-mid/

Comment: Thanks! I sorted it out! With the use of the 'len' function.

Comment: Glad i could help :)